# Paste files conditionally with bash if and awk loop

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, awk

I have a list of files that I want to paste to a master file (bar) if some awk condition is fulfilled.

```
for foo in *; 
do 
  if awk '*condition* {exit 1}' $foo   
  then                               
    :                        
  else 
    paste $foo > bar 
  fi 
done
```

However, it looks like only the last pasted file is in bar. Shouldn't paste add new columns to bar every time, without overwriting all the data completely?

```
File1    File2   Expected_Output    Actual_Output
1  4     1 NaN    1  4  1 NaN           1 NaN   
2  5     2  7     2  5  2  7            2  7
3  6     3  8     3  6  3  8            3  8
```

Comment: note you are using `paste $foo > bar`, which will delete any previous content in `bar`. You probably want to use `>>` to append.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `paste` command overwrites file `bar` at each iteration in the loop, which explains that at the end you only have the last file.

```
declare -a FILES=()
for foo in *; 
do 
  if awk '*condition* {exit 1}' $foo   
  then                               
    :                        
  else 
    FILES+=("$foo")
  fi 
done
paste "${FILES[@]}" > bar
```

This code accumulates all filenames that match your condition in an array named `FILES`, and calls `paste` only once, expanding all filenames into individual, quoted arguments (this is what `"${FILES[@]}"` does) and redirecting output to the `bar` file.

Additionally, you can replace the whole if/then/else block with :

```
awk '*condition* {exit 1}' "$foo" || FILES+=("$foo")
```

The `||` expresses a condition, and because of Bash performing a lazy evaluation of logical operators, the statement to the right is only executed if `awk` returns a non-zero return code.

Please note I quoted `"$foo"` (when passing it to `awk`) for the cases the name of your files would contain special characters.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem very elegantly. I thought that after each iteration the paste command should just add to the file the new columns, similar to what the bash append ">>" does. Apparently this is not the case.

Comment: You could always imagine an utility doing what you thought paste does, but it would be less efficient.  Please note I have added suggestions to my proposed solution so that you can further simplify your code (and correct the quoting).